# Java Threading: Is using interrupt() within run() acceptable to stop a thread when it is finished completing its task?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have setup a `Java` `Thread` class which preforms a particular task of creating a new `Process` and running it along with various other things.

In the parent class which invokes the `Thread` I have setup a loop

```
while(!thread.isActive()) {
...
}
```

I wanted to know if it is best practices / acceptable to update the `run()` in the `Thread` class to issue a `interrupt()`

```
run() {
  callTask();
  interrupt();
}
```

**Update**

I could then create a `boolean` `finished` field on the `Thread` and change that to true once the callTask() is completed and have the parent look for

Thread:

```
run() {
  callTask();
  finished = true;
}
```

Parent:

```
  // Start the threads for each Device
        for (DeviceRunner deviceRunner : deviceRunners) {
            deviceRunner.start();
        }

        boolean doneProcessingDevices = false;
        while (!doneProcessingDevices) {
            Set<DeviceRunner> deviceRunnersToRemove = new HashSet<DeviceRunner>();
            for (DeviceRunner deviceRunner : deviceRunners) {
                if (deviceRunner.isFinishedRunning()) {  // check to see if the thread is finished
                    deviceRunnersToRemove.add(deviceRunner);
                }
            }

            // remove the device runners which are no longer active
            deviceRunners.removeAll(deviceRunnersToRemove);

            if (deviceRunners.isEmpty()) {
                doneProcessingDevices = true;
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: You want the thread to `interrupt` its corresponding `Thread` object, basically interrupting itself?

Comment: You want a thread to interrupt itself?  What is the point of that?  The purpose of `t.interrupt()` is to get thread `t` to pay attention to some important thing that has changed (often, a "shutdown" request).  Your thread doesn't need to get its _own_ attention.  It already has its own attention.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis     I just setup the interrupt so that the parent thread knew when the thread was finished.  I noticed that even when the thread no longer had any tasks to do in the run() that thread.isActive continually returned true in some cases.

Should I just put in a boolean on the thread then and change it and have the parent look for that to be set for when the thread is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify: you don't have to stop threads manually. When `run()` completes, the native thread will die and the `Thread` object will be garbage collected.

If you want your parent to wait until all tasks completed, you can use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Initialize the latch with the number of tasks that have to be done. Every time a task finishes, let him invoke `countDown()`. In the meantime, your parent blocks on `await()`:

> Causes the current thread to wait until the latch has counted down to zero, unless the thread is [interrupted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--).

This MWE demonstrates the basic idea:

```java
int numberOfTasks = 3;
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfTasks);

while (numberOfTasks-- > 0) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            // Do stuff.
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } finally {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }).start();
}

try {
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("All tasks finished.");
} catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
```

You won't see `All tasks finished.` before each task has printed `Done.`.

Comment: I think I ran into a bug which lead me to believe that I needed to actually end the thread as it was continually set to alive.  It turns out the bug caused a certain section of the `task` to stay open and never finish which meant that the thread never finished run().  

Thanks for the details I will take a look to see if we should look into using this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are really looking for is `Thread.join` method. Copying from [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing, `t.join()`
>   causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates

Comment: I dont know when the thread is finished from the parent.  I only know when the thread is finished from inside the thread class.

Comment: You don't need to know that. You just call `join` and this will block your thread (the one that is calling `join`) until that other thread finishes.

Comment: Check above.  I am running multiple threads, each has the same task to complete, when they are done I want to remove them and finish.  What is the best practice to kill the thread from inside itself.
JOIN(): 
Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever. 
This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.